# RxJS5 - dummy observables

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs5

Sometimes we need a dummy observable because the RxJS API does not seem to accept null or undefined in certain cases, for example:

```
Queue.prototype.eqStream = function ($pauser) {

    if (!$pauser) {
        $pauser = Rx.Observable.timer(1);
    }

    let $obs = Rx.Observable.zip(
        this.obsEnqueue,
        pauser   // because pauser cannot be null here
    );
```

does RxJS5 have some accepted dummy Observable that just fires immediately, or should we just use one of these:

```
Rx.Observable.timer(1);
Rx.Observable.from([0]);
```

It would be nice if the RxJS5 API gave us an accepted dummy Observable, like:

```
Rx.Observable.dummy()
```

or something like that. Does anybody know the best practice when it comes to dummy Observables?

Comment: Is [`Rx.Observable.of`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of) what you are looking for?

Comment: is it just Rx.Oservable.of() with an empty argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an observable that immediately completes and emits nothing, use [`empty`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-empty):

```js
let dummy = Rx.Observable.empty();
```

If you want an observable that emits a value and then completes, use [`of`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of):

```js
let dummy = Rx.Observable.of('some value');
```

Comment: right, but I think I want an observable that fires both onNext() and onCompleted()

Comment: Updated. Use `of` if you want to emit a value before completing.

Comment: thanks I will use *Observable.of* like you did, appreciate it!